# How convert TeX tag to HTML tag using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How convert this tex

```
hello \o{test} how are you?
```

into that?

```
hello <span>test</span> how are you?
```

Comment: Do you need any **without** regex solution in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following expression:

```
\\o\{([^}]+)}
```

- `\\o` Matches `o`.
- `\{` Matches `{`.
- `([^}]+)` Capturing group. Matches and captures anything other than a `}`.
- `}` Matches a `}`.

Replacing with:

```
<span>\1<\/span>
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/n9K722/1).

---

**Sed** implementation:

```
$ echo "hello \o{test} how are you?" | sed -r 's/\\o\{([^}]+)}/<span>\1<\/span>/g'
hello <span>test</span> how are you?
```

---

**Php** implementation:

```
<?php
$input_lines="hello \o{test} how are you?";
echo preg_replace("/\\\\o{([^}]+)}/", "<span>$1<\/span>", $input_lines);
```

Prints:

```
hello <span>test<\/span> how are you?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Without** regex: using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php
$string = 'hello \o{test} how are you?';
echo str_replace(['\o{','}'],['<span>','</span>'],$string);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ttSC2

**With regex** using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$re = '/\\\\o\{([^}]+)\}/m';
$str = 'hello \\o{test} how are you?';
$subst = '<span>$1</span>';
echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FiOKO

Comment: Wow, your pattern is very similar to mine, isn't it?. The `{` and `}` do not need escaping in the pattern for php by the way.